# FirebaseJobDispatcher is not executing for every 5 seconds

Tags: android, service

I am trying to hit the server every 5 seconds.Previously I am using Alarm manager. After that I am used Job Scheduler. But when I install my app in Nougat devices this Job Scheduler is not running. So I am switching to FirebaseJobDispatcher. But FirebaseJobDispatcher is not executing for every 5 seconds. Herewith I attached the code which I am using.

```
public Job createJob(FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher){

        Job job = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                .setService(ScheduledJobService.class)
                .setTag("getTask")
                .setReplaceCurrent(false)
                .setRecurring(true)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 5))
                .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_LINEAR)
                .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
                .build();
        return job;
    }

public void scheduleJob(Context context) {
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
        Job job = createJob(dispatcher);
        dispatcher.mustSchedule(job);
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is it working every 1 min approx?

Comment: Yes. It's working some times for 1 min some times it takes two and more.

Comment: Yeah there is a limitation to it's firebase job dispatcher with API 24 or higher. It will be extended at least to 1 min. Use the Android frame work job service

Comment: I used Job android.app.job.JobService. It is working in lollipop and marshmallow. But not working as expected in Nougat. That's why I choose this. What about com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmTaskService? Now I am using this. It is working fine. But GCM is oldest one right? To replace GCM only Google introduce Firebase. So I have little fear to use com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmTaskService in my project. Any idea? plz..

Answer (score -1):

make sure that you register your service in Manifest [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-)